# Puppet Error: Must pass variable to Class[class_name]

Tags: error-handling, module, puppet

I am receiving the following error upon running

```
$puppet agent --test
$err: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Must pass rails_var2 to Class[class_name] at /etc/puppet/modules/module_name/manifests/init.pp:1 on node node_name
```

And What I'm seeing is that the init.pp does pass rails_var2 to the class_name.

```
class class_name ( $rails_var, $rails_var2 )
```

Which is defined within apache::vhost

```
apache::vhost { "somename.${rails_var}":
...
variable_app_env => $rails_var2
```

What could be going wrong here?

Comment: `class class_name ( $rails_var, $rails_var2 )` is a definition, not a declaration/invocation. `apache::vhost` is a different namespace than `class_name` and `$rails-var2` is non-global. There are probably a few other things wrong here, but lets start with those.

Comment: @MattSchuchard So is it giving me an issue because rails_var2 is never declared within class_name? Sorry, I'm not too familiar with the puppet language

Comment: In your snippets, you listed the definition of `class_name` as the declaration/invocation of `class_name`, and the declaration/invocation of `apache::vhost` as the defintion of `$rails_var2`.

Comment: @viviboox3, you have not presented the part of your code that is directly responsible for the error message you received.  That part is a [*declaration*](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/4.5/reference/lang_classes.html#declaring-classes) of class `module_name`.